# How to use refresh token in Oauth2.0?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, authorization

I understood that Refresh Token is used to get another access token after it expires. But, I am confused about how to use it.So, here is what my code looks like(I am building a app with Twitter API and the app uses Oauth2.0 authorization):

1. User sends request to my API server with access token and refresh token(stored in cookies)
2. In my server, when I make request to the Twitter API, first I request with access token--if the request is unauthorized(due to expired access_token) I use refresh token to get another access token and use that to make request.

This 2) codeblock for everytime I make a API request to the Twitter API is infuriating me. What is the better way to write. Am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included your code, so it's impossible to tell what might be incorrect about it. However, the process for using a refresh token is pretty straightforward. See [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code) (under Refresh tokens near the top) and [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) (at step 5) in the docs.

Essentially, you will make a POST call to https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token with a URL-encoded body. You will include the refresh token and a grant type of `refresh_token` in that body. Depending on whether your app is a confidential client or not, you'll include the client ID in the body or in the header with a client secret.

Whatever code you are using for the access token should be easily reusable with a few tweaks.